# Ошибка: Illegal string offset php массив

Tags: php, foreach

есть массив

```
 Array
    (
        [44] => Array
            (
                [id] => 44
                [title] => Категория 1
                [link] => #
                [parent_id] => 0
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [53] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 53
                                [title] => Категория 1_1
                                [link] => #
                                [parent_id] => 44
                            )
    
                        [57] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 57
                                [title] => Категория 45
                                [link] => #
                                [parent_id] => 44
                            )
    
                    )
    
            )
    
        [49] => Array
            (
                [id] => 49
                [title] => Категория 2_2
                [link] => #
                [parent_id] => 0
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [54] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 54
                                [title] => Категория 2_2
                                [link] => #
                                [parent_id] => 49
                            )
    
                    )
    
            )
    
        [51] => Array
            (
                [id] => 51
                [title] => Категория 3
                [link] => #
                [parent_id] => 0
            )
    
        [52] => Array
            (
                [id] => 52
                [title] => Категория 4
                [link] => #
                [parent_id] => 0
            )
    
        [55] => Array
            (
                [id] => 55
                [title] => Категория 44
                [link] => #
                [parent_id] => 0
            )
    
    )
```

Хочу получить в таком виде:

```
Категория 1
  Категория 1_1
  Категория 45
Категория 2_2
  Категория 2_2
Категория 3
Категория 4
Категория 44
```

Мой код :

```
foreach ($testing as $test_value) {
            echo $test_value['title'] . "<br>";
            foreach ($test_value as $value) {
                echo $value['title'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так

Comment: ну начните с того, чтобы брать массив для второго цикла из `$test_value['children']` и только в том случае, если такой ключ в массиве есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь из моего кода Вы поймете где у Вас ошибка

```php
<?php

foreach ($testing as $test_value) {
     echo "[-] ".$test_value['title'] . "<br>\n";
     if ( isset( $test_value['children'] ) && is_array( $test_value['children'] ) && count($test_value['children']) > 0) {
         foreach ($test_value['children'] as $value) {
             echo " |- ".$value['title'] . "<br>\n";
         } 
     }
}
```

Результат

```
[-] Категория 1<br>
 |- Категория 1_1<br>
 |- Категория 45<br>
[-] Категория 2_2<br>
 |- Категория 2_2<br>
[-] Категория 3<br>
[-] Категория 4<br>
[-] Категория 44<br>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Нужно было сделать проверку, на наличие детей, если есть то выводим.